# Should I give this crazy woman a gun?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In *Mass Effect 3*, you find several ambient conversations going on among the many different people on the Citadel. My personal favorite involves the PTSD (Post Traumatic Stress Disorder) sufferer in Huerta Memorial.

After making several visits for no reason other than to hear her finish the story, I wasn't surprised when she asked for a firearm. I *was* surprised when her psychiatrist said she'd see what she could do to get her patient said gun (since giving a gun to a PTSD patient of her caliber is about the same as lighting the fuse on a stick of dynamite, which in this case is sitting in the middle of a ***HOSPITAL***)!

I thought nothing of this until I saw a message on the Spectre terminal within the Embassies, giving me the option to authorize the request for a weapon!

**Does anything happen in terms of gaining/losing war assets, or anything else potentially harmful to my work up to this point, if I give this woman a gun (in the middle of a hospital)?**

Comment: Yes, you absolutely should give her the gun, and then report back with the consequences!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "PTSD Soldier" found in Huerta Memorial Hospital is actually an Asari Huntress named Aeian T'Goni. According to [these gentlemen](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-/62171998), if you approve the weapon permit for T'Goni, you will actually lose War Assets as an outcome of this reckless behavior.

More detailed information about T'Goni can be found on [this page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Aeian_T%27Goni).